# how to write a simple video player on android?

Tags: android

I have code for simple audio player on android. But it is not working for videos. Please guide me to write a simple video player.
The code of audio player is

```
package com.example.helloplayer;

public class HelloPlayer extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.file); 
        mp.start();
   }
}
```

Comment: Google (android developer, not like "google it" :) )already done it for you: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/media/VideoViewDemo.html

Comment: HI, Thanks for your reply. The problem is, that is too big project and it is giving hundreds of warning and I an not able to run the project. It is giving some error. So I wanted a simplest program to run a video.

Comment: Well, the answer below seems like what you want. Good luck!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

For making a video player you will have to make use of video view. a sample is shown below

Layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<VideoView android:id="@+id/videoView"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here i am  playing a video stored in "resource/raw" folder , "one" is the name of video file,you can replace it with name of your video file .also make sure that you are going to play an android supported video format

VideoplayerActivitvity

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.MediaController;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.VideoView;

public class VideoplayerActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    VideoView videoView =(VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView);
    MediaController mediaController= new MediaController(this);
    mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);        
    Uri uri=Uri.parse("android.resource://"+getPackageName()+"/"+R.raw.one);        
    videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
    videoView.setVideoURI(uri);        
    videoView.requestFocus();

    videoView.start();


    }
    }
```

Comment: What is the location I have to add the one file to? and how to define it in layout file?

Comment: @sr01853 I am not developing android applications now.If I remember it right the video was added to the "resource/raw" folder in the project .Don't know  eclipse is still using the same old project structure.