# how to playback video from internal storage(my app) with videoView

Tags: android, storage, android-videoview, internal

Im trying to play video from internal storage, but videoview cant play it.
Is there a way to do this and not by temporarily copying to sdcard and playing it?
The video was recorded with mediarecorder.

Comment: yes it is possible to play video  packed along with the resources check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6568054/how-to-write-a-simple-video-player-on-android/6568448#6568448)

Answer (score 1):

Use this code in your activity

```
 VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.video_view);
 MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
 mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);
 videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
 videoView.setVideoPath(getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath()+"/file_name.mp4");
 ideoView.start();
```

The file_name.mp4 must be created with Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE

Holp this helps