# Android - playing many videos from external storage - audio only and black screen

Tags: android, media-player, screen, external, android-videoview

In my app I'm having many short (1-2 secs) movies stored on external storage. One activity displays those videos. The problem is, when I am creating activity everything is fine. But when I'm replaying movie or changing movie, sometimes I get black screen (for beginning of video. But when videos are 1-2 sec it's not acceptable) with audio only.

Some posts suggest to use AsyncTask to play video. Unfortunately it didn't help.

Since video playing always works on activity creation I made some experiments with reloading whole activity, when user wants to replay or change video.
On fast video (activity) changing "cannot play video" message was shown.

Maybe it has something to do with android external memory management? Does anyone have any idea what am I doing wrong?

Code I'm using:

```
//on button click
public void navigateToNext(View view) {
    setNextVideo();
    refreshPlayer();
}

public void play(View view) {
    refreshPlayer();
}

public void refreshPlayer(){
    if(playingTask != null && !playingTask.isCancelled()){
        playingTask.cancel(false);
    }
    initPlayingTask();
}

private void initPlayingTask() {
    playingTask = new AsyncTask(){
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            String videoPath = getActualVideoPath();

            videoView.setVideoPath(videoPath);
            videoView.requestFocus();
            videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

                @Override
                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    mp.start();
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) {
            while(!this.isCancelled() && videoView.isPlaying());
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }

    };

    playingTask.execute();
}
```

I tried using mediaPlayers and surfaces. Tried to cache other mediaPlayers (preparing mediaplayer for next video, so when I wan't to play it I just changed players). Nothing seemed to help.

Videos are mp4.

Answer (score 0):

#### Just Replace your mp.start() --> videoView.start(); in your onPrepared or your can also try without implementing onPreparedListener

```
        videoView.setVideoPath(videoPath);
        videoView.requestFocus();
```

### use::

```
        videoView.start(); // As you are using mediaplayer to start that's why it's only playing sound with black screen

            OR

        videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPrepared() {
                videoView.start(); // As you are using mediaplayer to start that's why it's only playing sound with black screen
            }
        });
```

Hope it works for you!!

Comment: you can also visit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6568054/how-to-write-a-simple-video-player-on-android for better understanding :)